# Twitter Bootstrap FileUpload

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I would like to use the bootstrap-fileupload.js (http://jasny.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#fileupload) but I am confused on the event trigger.

How can I trigger an event sending the image to a web script (php for example) once a media asset is selected?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I recommend you to use https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload for file upload.

Comment: Thx for the recommendation. I like the preview feature of the boostrap-fileupload.js and that is why I was trying to find a how to trigger the evenf from this js. 
Appreciate the response, but I was already aware of jquery-file-upload.

Comment: I fail to see how this is possible. If you look at the source of jasny it uses the same name for the jquery function used by jquery.fileupload (both are called $.fileupload). Therefore it will be hard to use the two of them together.

Answer (score 6):

I stumbled upon similar problem where I wanted to upload an image via AJAX request as soon as the image is browsed/selected by user and update a hidden field with saved Image ID . I could not find the solution with bootstrap-fileupload.js. So below approach worked for me.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://malsup.github.com/jquery.form.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"> 
var options = { 
        success:       showResponse  // post-submit callback 
    }; 
    $(document).ready(function()
    {
        $('#photoimg').live('change', function()
        {
            $("#imageform").ajaxForm(options).submit();         
        });
    });

    function showResponse(responseText, statusText, xhr, $form)  { 
        $('#photoUrl').val(responseText);
    }
</script>
```

Image Form : ( must not be a nested form ! )

```
<form id="imageform" action="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/app/upload/saveimage" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                <div style="top: 25px">
                <div class="span6" style="margin-top: -545px; margin-left:680px">
                <div class="control-group">
                <label class="control-label " style="text-align: left">Photo: </label>
                <div data-fileupload="image" class="fileupload fileupload-new">
                    <div style="margin-left:-235px ;width: 150px; height: 150px; line-height: 150px;" class="fileupload-preview thumbnail" ></div>
                    <div>
                        <span class="btn btn-file" style="margin-right: 135px"><span class="fileupload-new" >Select image</span><span class="fileupload-exists">Change</span><input type="file" name="fileData" id="photoimg"/></span> <a data-dismiss="fileupload" class="btn fileupload-exists" href="#" style="margin-left: -75px">Remove</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                </div>

                </div>
                </div>
            </form>

<input type="hidden" name="individualCustomer.personInfo.photoUrl" id="photoUrl" />
```

Answer (score 1):

You can integrate it with jQuery File Upload (https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload) by removing the bootstrap.fileupload.js file as it has a naming conflict with jQuery File Uploader and will not work correctly with it. This means that you will not be able to use the more advanced features of the Jasny componenet. But I suggest you read the code and implement your own solution (it is not that hard :)).

The other thing you can do is use a different component for bootstrap. This component works well out of the box, no need to modify your markup: http://gregpike.net/demos/bootstrap-file-input/demo.html. It is simpler than the jasny component and therefore might be more suitable in some cases.