# AjaxFileUpload automatically upload file once selected

Tags: asp.net, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I have a standard AjaxFileUpload control

```
<asp:AjaxFileUpload ID="upManager" CssClass="fileUpload" runat="server" OnUploadComplete="upManager_UploadComplete" />
```

And instead of them having to press Upload, I just want the file to upload automatically once they have selected the file. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: You can refer to a solution, I used for a similar problem here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12372612/twitter-boostrap-fileupload/12471857#12471857 .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add reference to this script to `Scripts` collection of `ToolkitScriptManager` control or just put it at very bottom of page:

```
var legacyAddToQueue = Sys.Extended.UI.AjaxFileUpload.prototype._addToQueue;
Sys.Extended.UI.AjaxFileUpload.prototype._addToQueue = function(element){
    legacyAddToQueue.apply(this, [element]);
    this._doUpload();
}
```

Works well from console at this page: [AjaxFileUpload Demonstration](http://www.asp.net/ajaxLibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/AjaxFileUpload/AjaxFileUpload.aspx)

Also, in my opinion should be better to tweak ACT sources and add new property like `UploadAutomatically` to this control. Let me know if you'll prefer this option and need additional details about how to to such staff

UPDATED: try this script for new AjaxFileUpload (must work for new and old versions but not tested yet)

```
if (Sys.Extended.UI.AjaxFileUpload.prototype._addToQueue) {
    var legacyAddToQueue = Sys.Extended.UI.AjaxFileUpload.prototype._addToQueue;
    Sys.Extended.UI.AjaxFileUpload.prototype._addToQueue = function (element) {
        legacyAddToQueue.apply(this, [element]);
        this._doUpload();
    };
}else if(Sys.Extended.UI.AjaxFileUpload.Control){
    var legacyaddFileToQueue = Sys.Extended.UI.AjaxFileUpload.Control.prototype.addFileToQueue;
    Sys.Extended.UI.AjaxFileUpload.Control.prototype.addFileToQueue = function(fileItem){
        if(legacyaddFileToQueue.apply(this, [fileItem])){
            this._isUploading = true;
            this.enableControls(this._isUploading);
            this._processor.startUpload();
        }
    };
}
```

Comment: This code no longer works after the April 2013 update to the Ajax Control Toolkit

Comment: Awesome, I was actually about to get stuck into modifying it. Thanks for the quick response.

Comment: This code does work but it takes a very long time. I am not sure why. e.g. it goes to uploading instantly. Takes 15 seconds to then say uploaded. Then takes 10-15 seconds to remove the Upload button and say Uploaded next to the file.

Comment: Does upload work faster if you remove this script and upload files manually?

Comment: Actually no it doesn't. Apologies, my issue lies elsewhere. Thanks for all your help.

Comment: @YuriyRozhovetskiy The above code is not working with the latest AjaxControlToolkit stable release - Dec 2013. Would you please like to edit your code for the benefit of us :). Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

this works in the newest control toolkit

```
<asp:AjaxFileUpload onchange="$('.ajax__fileupload_uploadbutton').trigger('click');" runat="server" />
```

Comment: Nice catch. But I'm afraid this won't validate files on client and won't handle drag'n'drop files to control's drop area.

Answer (score 0):

you're right. Just replace it with

```
$(".ajax__fileupload").bind("change", function () { setTimeout(function () { $('.ajax__fileupload_uploadbutton').trigger('click'); }, 100); });
$(".ajax__fileupload_dropzone").bind("drop", function () { setTimeout(function () { $('.ajax__fileupload_uploadbutton').trigger('click'); }, 100); });
```

Comment: This almost works, but it triggers "Please Select File(s) To Upload" Modal, clicking ok on the Modal then triggers the upload automatically, but it's very confusing to the user.