# Twitter Bootstrap FileUpload issue

Tags: php, javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap

I would like to use [Twitter Boostrap FileUpload](http://jasny.github.io/bootstrap/javascript.html#inputmask) because I like the preview function it offers. This and some text I would like to post to a php script that does the uploading and adds info to a db. I dont necessarily need php to do the uploading of the file if javascript can do it I just need the link too it.

This question has been asked before but I can't find any working answer [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12372612/twitter-boostrap-fileupload). And no I dont want to use bootstrap file-upload that is suggested in the first answer.

In my php code I try to get the imgData with _FILE but its empty. How can I get this?

this is my form:

```
    <form action="php/service.php" method="post">
      <div class="control-group">
        <div class="fileupload fileupload-new" data-provides="fileupload">
            <div class="fileupload-preview thumbnail" style="width: 200px; height: 150px;"></div>
            <div>
                <span class="btn btn-file">
                    <span class="fileupload-new">Select image</span>
                    <span class="fileupload-exists">Change</span>
                    <input type="file" name="imgData" id="imgData" />
                </span>
                <a href="#" class="btn fileupload-exists" data-dismiss="fileupload">Remove</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="control-group">
        <textarea rows="3" id="text" class="" name="text" placeholder="Text..."></textarea>
    </div>
    <div class="control-group">
        <button type="submit" id="upload" class="btn" onclick="$('.fileupload').fileupload();">Upload</button>
    </div>
    </form>
```

in service.php:

```
if ($_FILES["imgData"]["error"] > 0) {
    echo "Error: " . $_FILES["imgData"]["error"] . "<br />";
} else {
    $fileExt = $_FILES["imgData"]["type"];
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set the encoding type for the form.

```
<form action="php/service.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

I also had difficulties with this bootstrap way of uploading files in IE. There might be some security issues in that one that prevents uploading.